# How can I correctly send data through 'PUT' with ajax in the request body like Backbone does

Tags: php, ajax, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest, put

I noticed that when saving data along with an id in backbone what it does is to send a 'PUT' request along with the data inside the request body ( in chrome dev tools appears as "request payload").
How can I achieve this with JQuery Ajax?
I have tried in several ways but none seems to send the data just like Backbone does.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/v2/users/request/test',
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "command": "on" }),
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown){
    }
})
```

in php I have this example on how to retrieve body data and display it:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT'){
            return file_get_contents('php://input');
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked inside `Backbone.sync` to see how Backbone does it? The Backbone source is pretty easy to follow.

Comment: @muistooshort set it as an answer it actually worked you way.
Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome to answer it yourself (and accept that answer), I just suggested somewhere to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Worked just by adding the content type explicitly to application/json:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```